# Entity Framework 6: cascade delete not showing in migrations

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I just upgraded my EF5 projects to EF6.

When I make an automatic migration file I see that it removes cascade deletes from entities. Even if I state it through fluentApi it still doesn't get configured the right way

In Example:

```
public class Publication
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? EventId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Event EventId { get; set; }
}
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
}
```

with the OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Using this:
    modelBuilder.Entity<Publication>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Event)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    //Or using this:
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Publications)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Event)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.EventId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    //Or even using both, doesn't work
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And what happens in my migration file (db was set up with EF5):

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Publications", "EventId", "dbo.Events");
    DropIndex("dbo.Publications", new[] { "EventId" });           
    CreateIndex("dbo.Publications", "EventId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Publications", "EventId", "dbo.Events", "Id");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Publications", "EventId", "dbo.Events");
    DropIndex("dbo.Publications", new[] { "EventId" });
    CreateIndex("dbo.Publications", "EventId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Publications", "EventId", "dbo.Events", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
}
```

So what is going wrong after I upgraded to EF6? When I was using EF5 my cascadeDelete was automatically set to true, so no problems there. I can imagine that cascadeDelete is now default false, but still using 1 of the above stated fluentApi expressions must do the trick?

Comment: I think this is a bug (see 2nd. link) - I am currently facing the same problem, and found the following informations (1 link seems to be written by you - but you did not get an answer):
[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66bcc4f3-bc4a-4879-8165-1b8f73c56206/entity-framework-6-cant-configure-cascade-delete?forum=adodotnetentityframework](Same question asked on msdn, but may be helpfull to others)
and the following bug, which has bee nconfirmed by EF Team, bot is not considered "important":
[https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2262]